# Illegal string offset 'properties', how to pass json encoded values

Tags: php, json, mongodb, echo, var-dump

how do I assign a field of a json_encoded result to a variable. I have the following:

```
$jsonres = json_encode($result); //where result is an array holding fields including name (string), properties (object type or array)
```

I tried the following:

```
echo $jsonres['properties']; // failed with "Illegal string offset 'properties'"
var_dump ($jsonres->properties); //"Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in..."
```

I need to be able to use the value of 'properties' in my form.

Thanks

Comment: In your example $jsonres is an object. Whereas `$jsonres['properties']` access element of array. You have to use object notation (o->prop).

Comment: @hindmost, sorry I don't get (o->prop). seems similar to what i put on   var_dump ($jsonres->properties); right?

Comment: Where is definition of `Response` class you using?

Comment: ok, pls assume I use: $jsonres = json_encode($result); I'll edit the question to avoid confussion or response

Comment: Result of `json_encode` is intended for use in Javascript, not in PHP. Obviously you have to use `json_decode` instead. Also if you want to use object notation you should pass 2nd argument of `json_decode`

Comment: the problem is i need the value of a field in json encoded format. is there a way to allocate this field to a variable? for instance $j=$jsonres['properties'] //fails

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem. Why you want to use json in PHP?

Comment: You want `properties` from the `$result` encoded in JSON right?

Comment: Provide value of `$result` variable.

Comment: @NeilLunn Yes I want properties from $result encoded in JSON.

Comment: @Kingsley You're very hard to understand. So I guess you have to: 1) decode $result to php array (or object); 2) retrieve needed property; 3) encode it to JSON.

Comment: Thanks @hindmost, you just gave me the logic to use. That's great :)

Comment: @hindmost, either post an answer of your own for Kingsley to accept, or Kingsley, accept my answer. You shouldn't leave a question unresolved.

Comment: @NobleUplift I can't suggest a solution since I still don't understand the problem. I've requested the details, but OP didn't provided it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply encode the properties property, not the entire object:

```
$jsonres = json_encode($result['properties']);
echo $jsonres;
```